# Convert Columns into Rows - SQL Server studio Management 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2010

I have 3 IDS columns that have thds of different values. I am trying to convert them into rows. I have tried an Unpivot method to no success.

```
 ID1     ID2     ID3
 12345   54321     53
 9954     8854     6565
 7844     54     
 8744
```

I woudld like my data to display in one column

```
 IDS
 12345   
 54321     
 53
 9954     
 8854 
 ECT..     

 Sample code below

 SELECT * IDS
```

FROM #UNIQUE as U

unpivot
 ( 
 for TaxIDS in ([id1],[id2],[id3])
 )as P

Any help would be appreciated...:)
 The more research I do the more I think unpivot is not the best route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selecting all non-null values:

```
select id1 as ids from your_table_name_here where id1 is not null union all
select id2        from your_table_name_here where id2 is not null union all
select id3        from your_table_name_here where id3 is not null
```

If you're only interested in the *different* values, try this:

```
select id1 as ids from your_table_name_here union
select id2        from your_table_name_here union
select id3        from your_table_name_here
```